Getting double slash and getting 301 moved permanently when manually changing url
So basicallly i am getting double slash when i try to use getOne like this
https://api.cibuilders.co.in/admin-pannel/project//2229
and the url of the page is
http://localhost:5173/admin-pannel/project/edit/2229
now when I try to manually change the getOne url from dataProvider like this
getOne: async ({ resource, id, meta }) => {
    const url = \${apiUrl}/${resource}${id}`;..}

then i am getting the correct url but getting this error that is 301 moved permanently and when i try to test the same url in postman its working perfectly fine
screenshot
To not get double slash without change the code in the dataProvider and to get the correct response as it is working in postman

You might have extra / in your resource name.
ie:
resources: [
  {
    name: 'books/'
  }
]

